# hive - how to set parquet/ORC as default output format

Tags: hive, parquet, orc

hive use Text as default format, a extra "store as parquet/ORC" clause have to be added if parquet/ORC file format is needed.
how to set parquet/ORC as default output format ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **hive.default.fileformat**
>
> Default Value: TextFile
> Added In: Hive 0.2.0
>
> Default file format for CREATE TABLE statement. Options are TextFile,
> SequenceFile, RCfile, ORC, and Parquet. Users can explicitly say
> CREATE TABLE ... STORED AS
> TEXTFILE|SEQUENCEFILE|RCFILE|ORC|AVRO|INPUTFORMAT...OUTPUTFORMAT... to
> override. (RCFILE was added in Hive 0.6.0, ORC in 0.11.0, AVRO in
> 0.14.0, and Parquet in 2.3.0) See Row Format, Storage Format, and SerDe for details.

---

> **hive.default.fileformat.managed**
>
> Default Value: none
> Added In: Hive
>
> 1.2.0 with HIVE-9915 Default file format for CREATE TABLE statement applied to managed tables only. External tables will be created with
> format specified by hive.default.fileformat. Options are none,
> TextFile, SequenceFile, RCfile, ORC, and Parquet (as of Hive 2.3.0).
> Leaving this null will result in using hive.default.fileformat for all
> native tables. For non-native tables the file format is determined by
> the storage handler, as shown below (see the StorageHandlers section
> for more information on managed/external and native/non-native
> terminology).

---

```
+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
|          |                                  Native                                   |             Non-Native              |
+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
| Managed  | hive.default.fileformat.managed (or fall back to hive.default.fileformat) | Not covered by default file-formats |
| External | hive.default.fileformat                                                   | Not covered by default file-formats |
+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
```

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties#ConfigurationProperties-FileFormats

Answer (score 2):

For external tables, execute the following:

```
set hive.default.fileformat=Parquet
```

For managed tables, execute the following:

```
set hive.default.fileformat.managed=Parquet
```

This would be set only for the current session. If you want to set these for your entire hive configuration, set these properties in your **hive-site.xml** and restart your hive service.